# Graph API not recognizing '#' in given filter string

Tags: javascript, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm trying to get the users from Azure AD using filter parameter. For example if I want the user with email ID "Alex.ferguson@mutd.com" , the following would be my request and this is working fine for the given email.

```
  var filteredUsers = await client
    .api("/users")
    .select("displayName,userPrincipalName,jobTitle,companyName,id")
    .filter("userPrincipalName eq 'Alex.ferguson@mutd.com'")
    .get();
```

But if the email has '#' character in it and my filter query would look like

```
"userPrincipalName eq 'wayne.rooney#Wazza#@mutd.com'"
```

The api is giving me 400 Bad request error.
the url path would look like this

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=displayName,userPrincipalName,jobTitle,companyName,id&$filter=userPrincipalName%20eq%20%27wayne.rooney
```

The email is getting trimmed at the first '#' character. What can I do about it. I have many users in my Azure AD with the email ID's having a '#' character. I tried using an escape character '' before '#', still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to encode the email.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=userPrincipalName eq 'wayne.rooney%23Wazza%23%40mutd.com'
```

and in your code

```
var filteredUsers = await client
.api("/users")
.select("displayName,userPrincipalName,jobTitle,companyName,id")
.filter("userPrincipalName eq 'wayne.rooney%23Wazza%23%40mutd.com'")
.get();
```

Comment: Still not working. How can I see the request URL? So that I can verify what exactly it converted the string into.